# Vertices coords and edges exporting

Tags: python, export, vertices, edges, coordinates

Is there a way in blender to export vertex coordinates as a numbered list along with a vertex to vertex edge list? I'll show briefly what I'm talking about.

1. x1 y1 z1
2. x2 y2 z2
3. x3 y3 z3

Edge list:

1. 1 2 (edge going from point 1 to 2)
2. 2 3
3. 3 1

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm sure that there is a way to do this with scripting. What did you try and where are you stuck?

Comment: The first part of listing the coords is quite simple although I can't write a running code that does that yet (Python newbie here, experienced in C++). The real problem is the latter - listing the edges.

Comment: Maybe this could help? At least, check it out:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/import_export.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each [edge](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.MeshEdge.html) contains the vertex index of the two vertices that it connects. Similarly each [face](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.MeshPolygon.html) contains a list of vertices defining it.

```
import bpy

obdata = bpy.context.object.data

print('Vertices:')
for v in obdata.vertices:
    print('{}. {} {} {}'.format(v.index, v.co.x, v.co.y, v.co.z))

print('Edges:')
for e in obdata.edges:
    print('{}. {} {}'.format(e.index, e.vertices[0], e.vertices[1]))

print('Faces:')
for f in obdata.polygons:
    print('{}. '.format(f.index), end='')
    for v in f.vertices:
        print('{} '.format(v), end='')
    print() # for newline
```

Comment: this script not running in latest version of blender, could you help please?

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can.

please check the [PATRICK BOELEN video](https://vimeo.com/23066396)

also you can [download and install the addon in order to export mesh data to TXT](http://pasteall.org/51127/python)

[Edit: links are dead, addon source code from some forum:]

```
bl_info = {

"name": "export mesh data to TXT",
"author": "PATRICK BOELEN",
"version": (1, 0),
"blender": (2, 7, 0),
"location": "View3D &gt; Tool Shelf",
"description": "EXPORT MESH DATA TO TXT",
"warning": "",
"wiki_url": "",
"category": "Import-Export"}

import bpy

class exportToTXT(bpy.types.Operator):
bl_idname = "export.export_to_txt"
bl_label =  "Export To TXT"

filepath = bpy.props.StringProperty(subtype="FILE_PATH")

def execute(self, context):
    obverts = bpy.context.active_object.data.vertices
    obfaces = bpy.context.active_object.data.polygons
    verts = []
    faces = []

    for vertex in obverts:
        verts.append(tuple(vertex.co))

    for face in obfaces:
        faces.append(tuple(face.vertices))

    file = open(self.filepath, 'w')
    file.write(str("datos de Vertices:   "))
    file.write(str(" "))
    file.write(str(verts))
    file.write(str(" "))
    file.write(str("datos de Caras:   "))
    file.write(str(" "))
    file.write(str(faces))

    return {'FINISHED'}

def invoke(self, context, event):
    context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
    return {'RUNNING_MODAL' }

class exportToTXTPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "Export_To_TXT"
    bl_label =  "Export To TXT"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"
    bñ_context = "objectmode"

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.operator("export.export_to_txt", text="Export to TXT")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score -1):

A quick and easy way (good enough for my occasional needs) is to export the model in a Wavefront .obj file, which is a text file.
In this format, objects are described as a list of 3D vertices (and then a list of textures, normals, facets etc).